# Nxginx rewrite url without redirection

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I would like to know if it's possible and how to rewrite an URL without redirection using nginx as web server. To be more precise, what I want is that when someone access to www.mydomain.com/auctions, the url rewrites to www.mydomain.com/subastas but without redirecting the browser to www.mydomain.com/subastas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `rewrite` commands are internal. You can also often accomplish the same result with the second parameter of `try_files`.

See documentation at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: You say "`rewrite` commands are internal". That has not been my experience (though I am new to nginx). I'm trying to do something very similar to OP, and nginx issues a 301 with my simple `rewrite` rule.

Comment: @jwd you should post some more information in a separate question/answer. Per documentation linked above, `rewrite` statement is supposed to issue a 301 only if you specify the optional `permanent` flag.

Comment: Yeah, I did just that: http://serverfault.com/questions/755168/nginx-access-same-content-from-multiple-urls   Not sure if this is the same issue as OP, but it's definitely strange to my (newbie) eyes.