# Nginx: Access same content from multiple URLs

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm trying to configure nginx so that the same static content can be accessed through two different URLs *without* any redirects.

For instance, if the client enters `/path/to/A` in their browser, I want that to retrieve the same content as `/path/to/B`.

I tried using `rewrite`, but Nginx seems to give me a 301 redirect in that case.

For example:

```
server {
    root /my/www/data;

    rewrite ^/path/to/A(.*)$ /path/to/B$1;
    # Note: /my/www/data/path/to/B *does* actually exist on disk.
    # However, the .../A version does not.
}
```

I guess one way to do this would be to symlink `/my/www/data/A` to point to `/my/www/data/B`, but I'm trying to do this using server config, not filesystem tricks.

My questions are:

1. How can this be done?
2. Under what circumstances does the `rewrite` module do an internal redirect vs. sending a 30x code to the client? I can't tell clearly from the docs.

Note: This is very similar to another question: [Nxginx rewrite url without redirection](https://serverfault.com/questions/698222/nxginx-rewrite-url-without-redirection)
However, that one is not very detailed.

**EDIT:** Here is a real config, with `curl` commands, etc:

First, the config:

```
server {

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/mydata;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    rewrite_log on;    
    rewrite ^/A(.*)$ /B$1 last;
}
```

Now, my web root contents:

```
$ find /usr/share/nginx/www/mydata/
/usr/share/nginx/www/mydata/
/usr/share/nginx/www/mydata/B
/usr/share/nginx/www/mydata/B/index.html
/usr/share/nginx/www/mydata/index.html
```

And with that running, here's what I get with `curl`:

```
$ curl -i 'http://localhost/A'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.1
...
Location: http://localhost/B/
...
<snipped>
```

However, I do note that `/A/` (with trailing slash) and `/A/index.html` work just fine:

```
$ curl -i 'http://localhost/A/'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
<snip - I see data for B/index.html, as I expect>
```

(Same results for `/A/index.html`).

So only in the first case do I get a 301 redirect, though my config never mentions such a thing explicitly.

What's the deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some experimentation, I found a few different solutions.

To recap, I want `/A` to stay as `/A` in the user's browser (no redirect to `/B`), but I still want it to display the content from `/B`.

**Option 1:** Use a symlink (:  This works, but you need access to the file system. Sidesteps the issue.

**Option 2:** Prevent the automatic trailing-slash 301 redirect by using an exact-match (`=`) location block:

```
location = /A {
    rewrite "" /B/;
}
# Note: the below should probably be inside a location block.
rewrite ^/A(.+)$ /B$1 last;
```

I found out about this from the [Nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

> without the trailing slash, a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended. If this is not desired, an exact match of the URI and location could be defined

**Option 3:** Use a redirect from `/A` to `/A/`, but do it manually, so it doesn't get returned to the client as a (rewritten) redirect to `/B/`:

```
location = /A {
    return 301 /A/;
}
location /A/ {
    rewrite ^/A/(.*)$ /B/$1 last;
}
```

I ended up going with option 3, since it makes `/A` behave just like `/B`, including the trailing-slash redirect (but to the right place, now).

Answer (score 1):

`rewrite` in `nginx` doesn't lead to 301 status in general (unless explicitly configured), so 301 is probably caused by other parts of your `nginx` config.

`rewrite` is the proper way to achieve what you want, your aproach is right.

Comment: I added a full example at the end — could you take a look? It seems like it does work in some cases, but not all of them. Anything obvious you see that I'm doing wrong? I'm still confused why I get a 301 when I never mentioned such things in my config at all...

Comment: Put  a  `rewrite` block inside the `location / {}` clause, this way your config gains readability +10 and straightfordwardness +20. Remove `try_files` entirely. In the future, try to avoid it, it's needed only in the case when you have no idea where the file could be (and in general you should). Let me know about the results.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of web servers showing directory indexes, for example Apache does the same. Whenever you request just "directory", it will redirect you to "directory/" like that.

Apache documentation is explicit about it, e.g. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html says

> A "trailing slash" redirect is issued when the server receives a request for a URL http://servername/foo/dirname where dirname is a directory. Directories require a trailing slash, so mod_dir issues a redirect to http://servername/foo/dirname/.

It seems nginx documentation is a fair bit more coy about it, e.g. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html just says:

> The ngx_http_autoindex_module module processes requests ending with the slash character (‘/’) and produces a directory listing. Usually a request is passed to the ngx_http_autoindex_module module when the ngx_http_index_module module cannot find an index file.

It doesn't explain the previous step, how the request get to ending with the slash, that seems to be implicit.

There's another old question on the network about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555428/nginx-causes-301-redirect-if-theres-no-trailing-slash

Comment: Okay, that makes some sense. But then why does /A redirect to /B/, rather than /A/? Or, more to the point, how can I make that be the case?  (I updated my question to include the `Location: ...` returned by the server.)

Comment: @jwd Because /A doesn't exist as a directory. It first applies your rewrite into /B, and then once it's there it sees a directory, and expands that implicitly into /B/.

Comment: Alright, I'll buy that. But I care most about the client's experience. If they visit `/A`, I want them to retain the same link (same path in their address bar, no redirect), but see the content from `/B`, just as though I had symlinked the directory (maybe that's what I'll end up doing). I'll try some of the ideas at the other link you presented and see what happens...

Comment: JFTR while I can remember hearing from about 4 picky people with regard to various intricate detials of URLs (which isn't a lot for about 20 years), I think it's highly doubtful that any such concerns are legitimate, as no real visitors would notice this kind of a distinction. They'll notice 404s, not minute optional details.

Comment: The trailing-slash redirect is not the main issue here. The main issue is that `/A` redirects to `/B/` rather than `/A/`. Just to make it concrete: I have a bunch of sequential pages, at locations like `/posts/123`. I want this link to work: `/posts/latest`, which would redirect to the current highest-numbered post. I want users to be able to put `/posts/latest` into their browser and today see the content for `/posts/12` but tomorrow see `/posts/13` if a new one were added. Seems reasonable, no? I don't want them to have to re-type `/posts/latest` every time, it should be a stable link.

Comment: Sorry, by "... would redirect to ..." I meant to write "... would show the same content as ..." The whole point is to avoid the redirect (:

Comment: Found a slightly more clear mention of the trailing slash redirect in the nginx docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location  (see text reading: "In response to a request with URI equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned")